# How can I find elements by xpath using selenium in python, if xpaths is dynamic and it's different for each element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

This is the fragment of my code. I'm trying to get access to property offers data, but the page is specific and for every offer, XPath contains 8 digit ID. Currently output shows me only data for one offer. When I change something here, selenium can't find element. I tried looking for class, which is same for every offer, but it's not working - same issue. I've already spent a few hours trying to fix it. The next problem will be how to avoid showing one offer multiple times, as it is right now, but the main thing is how to reach other offers. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.immobiliare.it/search-list/?idContratto=1&idCategoria=1&idTipologia%5B0%5D=7&idTipologia%5B1%5D=31&idTipologia%5B2%5D=11&idTipologia%5B3%5D=12&criterio=rilevanza&__lang=it&fkRegione=tos&idProvincia=LI&idNazione=IT&pag=1"

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(url)

offers = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"nd-list__item")

offer_list = []

for offer in offers:
    title = offer.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="link_ad_71883344"]/div/div[2]/a').text
    m = offer.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="link_ad_71883344"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div').text
    price = offer.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="link_ad_71883344"]/div/div[2]/div[2]').text
```

I tried look for other elements, also tried adding "contains" to XPath, but maybe in a wrong way.
After changes, an error is appearing

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Comment: You should be filtering by class `in-realEstateResults__item`, then you have the class `in-card__title`, `in-realEstateListCard__priceOnTop` and for `m` you could search for `aria-label="superficie"` what's your xpath by class that fails?

Comment: Use xpath to find all elements by class name that you are interested in.

Comment: @Daviid yes there were classes 'nd-list__item' and 'in-realEstateResults__item' divided so I used the first one. Now it's corrected. 
Next, I found titles by class 'in-card__title' and it works
I found price by 'in-realEstateListCard__priceOnTop'
still I have some issues with square meters. I tried both 'in-feat__data' and 'in-mainFeatures__text'. They are not causing errors, neither I can see the output. 
aria-label="superficie" is causing error

Comment: + I'm stuck one the first page (25 positions)

Comment: Update your qeustion then, post the new code. As for the page, just change `pag=1` to `pag=2`

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.immobiliare.it/search-list/?idContratto=1&idCategoria=1&idTipologia%5B0%5D=7&idTipologia%5B1%5D=31&idTipologia%5B2%5D=11&idTipologia%5B3%5D=12&criterio=rilevanza&__lang=it&fkRegione=tos&idProvincia=LI&idNazione=IT&pag=1"

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
offers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@id,'link_ad')]")

offer_list = []

for offer in offers:
    title = offer.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
    offer_list.append(title.text)
    price = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='in-realEstateListCard__priceOnTop']")
    offer_list.append(price.text)
    m = offer.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[text()='m²']//parent::div")
    offer_list.append(m.text)

print(offer_list)
```

Console output:

```
["Villa unifamiliare via dei Forcioni 468, Campo nell'Elba", '€ 750.000', '255\nm²', 'Baita, buono stato, 90 m², Centro, Campiglia Marittima', '€ 300.000', '90\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare Località Bargingo 1, Rosignano Solvay, Rosignano Marittimo', '€ 330.000', '185\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare Complesso residenziale LOC. CASONE ALLA SUGHERA, Piombino', '€ 195.000', '100\nm²', 'Appartamento in villa via Giovanni Berti Mantellassi, Rosignano Solvay, Rosignano Marittimo', '€ 590.000', '148\nm²', 'Terratetto unifamiliare 99 m², buono stato, Centro, Campiglia Marittima', '€ 170.000', '99\nm²', 'Terratetto plurifamiliare via del Glicine, Quercianella, Livorno', '€ 647.000', '180\nm²', 'Casale via dei Forni, Suvereto', '€ 780.000', '465\nm²', 'Ville unifamiliari e Appartamenti di nuova costruzione a Rosignano Marittimo', 'da € 145.000', '60\nm²', 'Appartamento in villa via della Prugnoliccia 91, Montenero Basso - Montenero Alto, Livorno', '€ 420.000', '148\nm²', 'Villa plurifamiliare via del Limoncino 21, Limoncino - Valle Benedetta, Livorno', '€ 685.000', '468\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare via delle Mimose, Procchio, Marciana', '€ 1.500.000', '300\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare via Pisana-Livornese Sud, La Chiusa, Collesalvetti', '€ 990.000', '420\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare via LO SCHIOPPO 4, Marciana Marina', '€ 6.500.000', '560\nm²', 'Casale Località La Vivalda, Suvereto', '€ 530.000', '756\nm²', 'Terratetto unifamiliare piazza dei Mille, Via Grande - Piazza della Repubblica, Livorno', '€ 97.000', '104\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare via dei Cavalleggeri, Vada, Rosignano Marittimo', '€ 680.000', '275\nm²', "Villa unifamiliare Località Capo d'Arco, Rio", '€ 330.000', '79\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare, ottimo stato, 380 m², Procchio, Marciana', '€ 1.850.000', '380\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare via Soprana, Centro, Capoliveri', '€ 453.000', '170\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare via delle Caldanelle, Campiglia Marittima', '€ 585.000', '190\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare via Luigi Einaudi, Centro, Portoferraio', 'Prezzo su richiesta', '250\nm²', "Casale via Torretta Vecchia 14, Castell'anselmo, Collesalvetti", '€ 520.000', '220\nm²', 'Villa bifamiliare via Aurelia 850, Chioma, Nibbiaia, Rosignano Marittimo', '€ 720.000', '391\nm²', 'Villa unifamiliare Località Naregno, Naregno, Capoliveri', '€ 3.800.000', '3.160\nm²']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**NOTE:** Above code scrapes only page 1. If you want to scrape more pages you can do that by enhancing the code.